# Add a button to `viewContainer` that is *always visible* in VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VSCode extensions, there are many different ways of adding buttons, specifically via [the `menus` contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus). While there is `view/*` stuff, there does not seem to be `viewContainer`.

Two questions:

1. Am I misreading this, or is there no way to add a button to the `viewContainer` title?

   - Note: The built-in `viewContainers` have them, e.g.: [image]
2. Even if that is not possible, is there maybe another way to somehow have a button appear, that is **always visible**, but within the `viewContainer`?

   - For example: buttons contributed to `view/title` only show up, if the mouse hovers over them or if the view is selected.
   - Note1: I am not asking for `editor/title` etc, but, specifically, buttons inside my custom `viewContainer`.
   - Note2: we sometimes use `TreeView` items as buttons, but aside from that.
   - Note3: I would largely prefer not having to manage a Webview in that `viewContainer`. I don't need one (despite a `webview` of course being able to deliver that functionality).

Comment: in the current VSC only the non-TreeView ViewContainers have these buttons like `Search` and `Run and Debug`, and the internal extension API has more options, how are these `Search` buttons defined in the code.

Comment: @Mark The visibility of these menu buttons is controlled by the `when` property, you specify for which view you want that button. Maybe if you set `"when": "true"` you will see the button always but then at different views. IN one of my extensions I have a `view/title` menu option but it only shows when the view has focus and thus the `when` property evaluates to true.

Comment: @rioV8 I am using the method shown here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions Using `"group": "navigation"` in the `view/title` and the icons for commands go into the `commands` section, and I am using no `when` clause.  Have you seen this reference I cited - it is "fairly" good.  I could add a gif to an answer I suppose.

Comment: Edited: @rioV8 I am not using any `when` clause in the `commands` section.  And they always show (at least in debug mode which is the only place thus far I am using those buttons - but I don't think that makes a difference here.)   The `vIewContainers` syntax is messy, note that in the package.json that `viewContainers` is a collection of two ojbects (activityBar and panel) which are themselves collections of viewcontainers; whereas `command` is just a collection of commands as it should be.

Comment: @Mark all menu items have `when` properties to specify the view where the button should go `"when": "view == nodeDependencies"`. with `group` you specify if it is in the title bar (visible when focus) or in the `...` menu of the title bar

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, I do have that `when` clause but it is just `"when": "view == editor-groups"`.  The view doesn't need to be focused for that to be true - if it is the only view in the Side Bar visible at the time.